# How to extract text from brochure images using pytesseract

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I've tried to extract text from the brochure image:

[brochure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4nom.png)

**Code:**

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

im_folder = 'img_path'
im_gray = cv2.imread(im_folder+'/'+'big-bazaar-wed-offer-may-21-2014.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

#converting image to binary image
(thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

#enhancing the image size
img = cv2.resize(im_bw,None,fx=4,fy=4, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
cv2.imwrite('im_enhance.png',img)

#Text extraction
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('im_enhance.png'))
print(text)
```

Since this a brochure image, I've converted it into binary image and enhanced it to achieve better OCR results.

I'm able to extract texts using this code but some texts couldn't be extracted especially the amount/prices.

What changes should I make inorder to extract all the texts?